# What are the MOST Important Things to Configure on a WAF? Specifically Barracuda Web Application Firewall

Tags: cloud, web-applications, security, web-application-firewall

I will be hosting a web application on a cloud provider. This will be protected behind a WAF specifically Barracuda's Web Application Firewall Vx.

I do not have too much experience with WAF security. I believe we will block most ports from the cloud firewall.

What are other really important things to configure (or to make sure it is set) within a WAF?
I really don't have too much knowledge of web based attacks.

Some policies I looked at were request limits, cookie security, parameter protection, and cloaking.

I've been going through the logs to try to cover any false positives generated which I believe I cleared so now its time to make this secure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Beside usual configuration item (log rotation/exporting, monitoring, backup ...) , you will need to have a **strong process to detect/monitor** for false positive and white list the impacted item fast.

If your Waf is getting auto update frequently, wich is a good practice, you can get trap into very nasty blocking policy without notice.

Rate limit should also be configure but it definitly depend on how you handle denial of service and others alike abuses .